# click on Gallery picture but pictures doesn't appear

Tags: images

When I click on the gallery pics I get the hover name it shows a circle of arrows that it is working but no pics show up.

The website is: http://www.jeremyscircle.org/en_US/gallery/

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Following are the two errors at console

- `Failed to load resource: the http://www.jeremyscircle.org/favicon.ico server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`
- `Failed to load resource: the http://www.jeremyscircle.org/en_US/gallery/ server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)**

The 500 code would normally indicate an error on the server, not anything with your code. Some thoughts

- Talk to the server developer for more info. You can't get more info directly.
- Verify your arguments into the call (values). Look for anything you might think could case a problem for the server process. The process should not die and should return you a better code, but bugs happen there also.
- Could be intermittent, like if the server database goes down. May be worth trying at another time.